# Isometric embeddings of $\ell_q^m$ into $\ell_p$ and $L_p$ for $p,q\in[1,+\infty]$

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I'm looking for articles describing (or proving nonexistence) of isometric embeddings of $m$-dimensional space $\ell_q^m$ into $L_p$ and $\ell_p$ for $q,p\in[1,+\infty]$.

Since $\ell_q^m$ is finite dimensional some (not necessary isometric) embedding always exist. I'm interested in isometric ones.

Thank you for taking time.

Comment: It's not exactly addressing your question, but did you see [this blog post](http://calculus7.org/2012/08/07/isometric-embeddings-of-finite-dimensional-normed-spaces/) by Leonid Kovalev? He recommends the book by [Milman and Schechtman](http://books.google.com/books/about/Asymptotic_Theory_of_Finite_Dimensional.html?id=tTnvAAAAMAAJ) for the "real stuff".

Comment: what does "real stuff" mean?

Comment: I'm only quoting him. I suppose he means that the sharpest known embedding constants between finite-dimensional $\ell_p$-spaces and much more can be found there. I don't know the book, but given the reputation of its authors it's probably worth a look. // You said elsewhere that you were reading the book by Albiac-Kalton. The chapter on local theory should contain something, too.

Comment: @commenter Yes using result on embedding of $\ell_q$ in $L_p$ we can get some partial progress. The case $p=\infty$ is also of small interest because every separeable space ismotrically embedded in $\ell_\infty$ and $L_\infty$.

Comment: @commenter I've got an answer on MO, see my answer below.

Comment: Thanks, Bill Johnson to the rescue :)

Comment: @commenter As usually, he is just awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer to this question on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111039/isometric-embeddings-of-ell-qm-into-ell-p-and-l-p-for-p-q-in1-infty).